# How to use multiple PUT fuctions in Web api C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Multiple put method working in local iis, but not in live server.

```
         Webapi Config:

     config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "ApiById",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "ApiByName",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "ApiByAction",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "ApiByActionName",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );


   [HttpPut]

    public async Task<int> DeleteCity(Guid? Id)
    {
        City updateCity = await db.City.Where(x => x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        updateCity.IsActive = 0;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return 1;
    }


    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/city/DeleteCitys/{Id}")]
    public async Task<int> DeleteCitys(Guid? Id)
    {
        City updateCity = await db.City.Where(x => x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        updateCity.IsActive = 1;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return 3;
    }
```

http://freedompg.softwarecubes.com/api/city/76F84F4C-22C8-4EF8-B593-B3605CF9AD14

Output : 1 is Correct

http://freedompg.softwarecubes.com/api/city/DeleteCitys/76F84F4C-22C8-4EF8-B593-B3605CF9AD14

Output : 1 is wrong (call the previous function)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this. You need to have the route for the DeleteCity also

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/city/{Id}")]
public async Task<int> DeleteCity(Guid? Id)
{
    City updateCity = await db.City.Where(x => x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    updateCity.IsActive = 0;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return 1;
}


[HttpPut]
[Route("api/city/DeleteCitys/{Id}")]
public async Task<int> DeleteCitys(Guid? Id)
{
    City updateCity = await db.City.Where(x => x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    updateCity.IsActive = 1;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `RoutePrefix` for your controller and `Route` for methods

```
[RoutePrefix("api/City")]
public class CityController : Controller
{
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("DeleteCitys")]
    public async Task<int> DeleteCitys(Guid[] Id)
    {
        // Your Code
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("DeleteCitys/{Id}")]
    public async Task<int> DeleteCitys(Guid? Id)
    {
        // Your Code
    }
}
```